# Automatic transfer of annotations in sideloaded book in Nook Android app

Tags: nook, android, annotations, synchronization

I have a couple non-Nook Android devices with the Nook app installed on them -- a tablet and a phone -- and several epub books that I read and annotated on the tablet. I was surprised, when I copied my epub files over to my phone, to see that highlighting and notes in at least two of those ebooks was carried over.

I can't find anything online about B&N synchronizing annotations for sideloaded ebooks in the cloud; nor can I find any information on how to do it myself. Also, I notice that no new annotations I create on either device get propagated to the other; I wonder if perhaps B&N was actively saving such annotations in the past but no longer is.

My main question is: **how can I consistently synchronize annotations between devices in sideloaded books using the Nook app?** Secondarily, I'm curious as to how and why some of my annotations were able to be brought across already.